# Color only underline in Swift

Tags: swift, label, nsattributedstring, underline

How do i change the color of my underline in a label? I want only the underline to change color, and not the entire text.

I have used this code to get the underline:

```
let underlineAttribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(nearSavings[indexPath.row]) ,-", attributes: underlineAttribute)
cell.detailTextLabel?.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
```

But i cant find the code, to set the underline color. Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 11):

## Swift 4 Solution

You must use NSAttributedString with an array of attributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any].

Sample code:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Colored Underline Label
        let labelString = "Underline Label"
        let textColor: UIColor = .blue
        let underLineColor: UIColor = .red
        let underLineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue

        let labelAtributes:[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]  = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: textColor,
            NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: underLineStyle,
            NSAttributedStringKey.underlineColor: underLineColor
        ]

        let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: labelString,
                                                           attributes: labelAtributes)

        myLabel.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to add a single line border under the label, that acts as an underline.

Get reference to the label

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
```

Add the border under the label

```
    let labelSize = myLabel.frame.size
    let border = CALayer()
    let w = CGFloat(2.0)

    border.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor  // <--- Here the underline color
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: labelSize.height - w, width:  labelSize.width, height: labelSize.height)
    border.borderWidth = w
    myLabel.layer.addSublayer(border)
    myLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

> Note: with this workaround you underline the whole label. If you need to partially undlerline the text this solution is not appropiate

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 Solution

```
class UnderlinedLabel: UILabel {

override var text: String? {
didSet {
    guard let text = text else { return }
    let textColor: UIColor = .black
    let underLineColor: UIColor = .lightGray
    let underLineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
    let labelAtributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]  = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: underLineStyle,
        NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: underLineColor
    ]
    self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: labelAtributes)
    }
}
```

}

Usage:
Just give class UnderlinedLabel to your label in the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

The `NSAttributedStringKey.underlineColor` attribute does what you want:

```
let underlineAttributes = [
   NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
   NSAttributedStringKey.underlineColor: UIColor.orange
] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Test", attributes: underlineAttributes)
```

This will set the underline color to orange whereas the text color will remain black.